# C++ edit value in 2d array

Tags: c++, pointers

```
void update(bool **board){
    *(*(board + 2) + 1) = true;
}

int main(){
    bool board[3][2] = { false };

    update(board);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            if (board[i][j] == true){
                cout << "board[" << i << "][" << j << "] is true;" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where am I wrong? Also, can you please talk some more about arrays and pointers?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: "Where am I wrong?" Start by telling us what this issue is. "Also, can you please talk some more about arrays and pointers?" This is too broad for SO, read a C++ book instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a function

```
void update(bool **board){
    *(*(board + 2) + 1) = true;
}
```

it's wrong to call it using:

```
bool board[3][2] = { false };
update(board);
```

`board` decays to `bool (*)[2]`, not `bool**`.

You need to define `update` as:

```
void update(bool (*board)[2]){
     board[2][1] = true; // Simpler
}
```

Comment: Or `bool board[][2]`.